# Trouble with Angular parser in custom directive using templating service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, nested

Long time lurker first time poster. I'm pretty new to angular, but I'm building a little app that dynamically generates a form based on a JSON schema retrieved via a ticketing system API. I've tried to avoid hardcoding as much as possible here as the schema may change if custom fields are added in the ticket system.

So far the app loads the schema and builds input fields and uses the "@data-type" to determine which type of template to apply.

The issue is that I'm struggling to get my final output JSON like I want it.

**Desired JSON Output**

```
{
  "Custom_Field": [
    {
      "@id": "120207",
      "#text": "1234569789"
    },
    {
      "@id": "121264",
      "Option": {
        "@id": "265946",
        "@viewOrder": "1",
        "Value": "North America"
      }
    },
    {
      "@id": "125734",
      "#text": "Legacy Account Number"
    }
  ],
  "Account_Name": "Example Account",
  "Modified_By": "John Doe"
}
```

Specifically I'm a bit stuck on how to best handle my nested objects nested in arrays. For example each object in the "Custom_Field" array would be rendered as an input field, but should still be indexed in that Custom_Field array.

Additionally, the parseCustomField() function doesn't seem to be working after loading in a template with my template service.

Anyways this is my attempt at making reusable code as a noob, but definitely open to suggestions on anything seen here really.

**JSON Schema (some objects removed for brevity)**

```
{
"?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "Account": {
    "Account_Name": {
      "@display-name": "Account Name",
      "@required": "true",
      "@editable": "true",
      "@field-type": "text",
      "@data-type": "string",
      "@max-length": "256"
    },
    "Date_Created": {
      "@display-name": "Date Created",
      "@required": "false",
      "@editable": "false",
      "@field-type": "usdate",
      "@data-type": "date"
    },
    "Custom_Field": [
      {
        "@id": "121264",
        "@display-name": "Support Region",
        "@required": "true",
        "@editable": "true",
        "@field-type": "dropdown",
        "@data-type": "option",
        "@multi-value": "false",
        "Option": [
          {
            "@id": "265946",
            "@viewOrder": "1",
            "Value": "North America"
          },
          {
            "@id": "265949",
            "@viewOrder": "3",
            "Value": "Europe"
          },
          {
            "@id": "265953",
            "@viewOrder": "2",
            "Value": "Asia"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@id": "125734",
        "@display-name": "Legacy Account Name",
        "@required": "false",
        "@editable": "true",
        "@field-type": "text",
        "@data-type": "string",
        "@max-length": "1024"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**App (Mashed together but usually separated out)**

```
app.controller('FormController', function($scope, pSchema) {

    // Initialize User Input Scope
    $scope.userinput = {};
    $scope.userinput.Custom_Field = [{}];

    // Load Schema
    $scope.loadschema = function(schematype) {
        pSchema.loadSchema(schematype).success(function(data) {
            $scope.schema = data[Object.keys(data)[1]];
        });
    }

});

app.directive('fieldItem', function ($compile, $parse, TemplateService) {

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        if (!angular.isArray(scope.field)) {

            templater(scope.field['@data-type']); 
            parseCustomField();

                // Quasi Work Around
                // Models the data correctly in the userinput.Custom_Field Array, but original bindings aren't really desired for each Custom_Field item on userinput.
                /*
                if('id' in attrs) { 
                    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (oldValue, newValue) {         
                        if (newValue != oldValue) {
                            var parentNode = scope.$parent.key; //Evaluates to "Custom_Field"   
                            var i = scope.$index;

                            if (angular.isObject(newValue)){
                                var newObj = {
                                    '@id' : attrs.id,
                                    'Option' : newValue
                                };                      
                            } else {
                                var newObj = {
                                    '@id' : attrs.id,
                                    '#text' : newValue
                                };
                            }
                            scope.userinput[parentNode][i] = newObj;
                        }
                    });     
                }
                */  

        } else {
            templater('array');             
        }

        //Helper Functions
        //Request Template
        function templater(field_type) {
            TemplateService.getTemplate(field_type).then(function (response) {  
                element.html(response.data);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
        //Parse Data
        function parseCustomField(){
            var toModel = function (val) {
                return {
                    '@id': attrs.id,
                    '#text':val                 
                }
            };                  
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(toModel);
        }
    }

    //Directive Configuration
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: linker
    };

});

app.factory('TemplateService', function ($http) {
    var getTemplate = function (content) {
        if (content != null) {
            return $http.get('/js/templates/' + content + '.html');
        }
    };
    return {
        getTemplate: getTemplate
    };
});

app.factory('pSchema', function($http) {
    return {
        loadSchema: function(type) {
            var url = "/js/models/schema/"+type+".json";
            return $http.get(url);
        }       
    };
});
```

**String.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{field["@display-name"]}}</label>
    <input ng-model="userinput[key]" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**Array.html (open to ideas on better ways to do this too maybe without a template)**

```
<field-item ng-model="userinput[key]" ng-repeat="(key,field) in field" id="{{field['@id']}}"></field-item>
```

**Index.html**

```
<form ng-controller="FormController" ng-model="userinput">
    <field-item ng-repeat="(key,field) in schema"></field-item>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your actual question is. Be careful not to chase after an XY question. So, a few comments with that regard: 1) remove everything that is not essential to the problem (do only have issues with `CustomFields` or more generally), 2) Explain clearly what the final output/JSON/DOM structure should be (say, if you were to hard-code it), 3) try to break down the problem into smaller bits (and perhaps multiple questions) - do you need to dynamically create DOM elements, do you need to maintain a certain ViewModel structure?, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to make it a bit more clear. In a nutshell:

1) I've dynamically created my DOM elements for the most part, but I'm having trouble keeping the view structure with objects nested in arrays.

2) My $parsers don't seem to be applied when using my templating service.

Comment: I'm asking about your use case, not a behavior.

Comment: Sure thing! In short I'm building up a set of tools so that I can better interact with the ticketing system I'm using and do things like mass imports and syncing accounts, contacts, etc with other systems. The form example here is really my attempt at building a dynamically created and interactive view model that is as faithful to the schema as possible, but still able to handle schema changes if they occur.

Comment: Ultimately, my absolute end goal is to allow a user to map two schemas from two different systems, save this model to a database, and use it for a two way sync for accounts, contacts, etc. This is just my first step at getting/setting data from my ticketing system.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you are after, but this question is really broad. Try to make a conceptually consistent but simpler (i.e. not as expressive) example and tackle issues one by one, probably over multiple questions. A plunker could help. Also, consider isolate scope - this would help with arrays. You also may not need your `TemplateService` - just use `ng-include`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry for the huge delay, but I ended up actually changing my model around. It ended up being easier to break out the custom fields from an array.